# Closing Session in Opentok

Tags: javascript, c#, opentok

I am creating an app which has a client and an admin. the Client publishes their video to the Admin which then talk them through technical assistance.

I am using Opentok React library, and Opentokcore sdk in C#.

The issue is I want to be able to disconnect the session from the server (or from the Admin side). I dont want to allow the client to put down their phone and forget to shut it off and keep publishing and costing $. I also want to be completely secure, not just mostly secure.

I am able to disconnect the stream, by calling the following javascript command from the admin side:

```
sessionHelper.forceUnpublish(streamOrStreamId, completionHandler)
```

This completely kills the stream, which is good.

The problem is, the Client can create a new stream using the Opentok token they have already been provided? im aware I can make that token expire, but I would rather be able to kill a token/session so it was no longer able to be used to create streams.

I could do it in Javascript, C# or Rest API.

Answer (score 0):

OpenTok Developer Advocate here.

On the client, you should subscribe to the `sessionDisconnected` event on the session. The `sessionDisconnected` event will carry a `reason` in the event.  If the reason is `forceDisconnected` you know that the disconnect occurred due to a moderator calling `forceDisconnect()`.

In that case, you can do some clean-up like clearing the token, session, etc.

You can learn more about the SessionDisconnectEvent at https://static.opentok.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/SessionDisconnectEvent.html

Comment: The problem with this approach; we are assuming the user isn't malicious and saved the token to use it to open more sessions and cost the account money.. I was a way to shut it off completely st the server side  so it was impossible to reopen

Comment: There's no way to explicitly destroy a session.  The best approach today would be to do the clean-up mentioned above and use short-lived tokens to limit potential exposure.

Comment: When tokens expire do they close the session? I ran some tests and it doesnt look like they do?  For example if I set token for 30mins expire.snfnthey leave session open it keeps running they can't use it to reopen session but it won't stop running session